# Getting 'crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated' error when running 'npm run dev' with React and Django. How can I resolve this issue?

Tags: reactjs, django

I'm developing a project using Django as an API, with React as the frontend. I'm following a tutorial on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEmjBEDyVSY&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-kCLWnGmK0jUBmGLaJxvi4j&index=4

When I run `npm run dev` it compiles everything successfully, however, when I head to my website I receive the error 'crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.'

I can get my website to run by using `python manage.py runserver` simultaneously, but in the tutorial, he doesn't do that at all and only uses `npm run dev`.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
}
```

Webpack Config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',  // path to our input file
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',  // output bundle file name
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/frontend'),  // path to our Django static directory
    clean: true,  // removes old bundles
  },
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',  // enable dev server to display correct file names
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: { presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/, // Add a loader for CSS files
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        type: 'asset/resource'
      }
    ],
  },
  watch: true
};
```